# Измерение скорости автомобиля в Android

Tags: android, gps

Подскажите, какой способ лучше подходит для измерения скорости движения автомобиля: с помощью GPS или посредством акселерометра? А также какое средство лучше всего подходит для измерения расстояния, которое проехал автомобиль?

Comment: акселерометр измеряет ускорение, а не скорость/растояние. Если автомобиль будет ехать равномерно, то у него будет нулевое ускорение и акселерометр ничего не покажет. Так что Ваш друг - это gps.

Comment: @KoVadim, но если мы знаем начальную скорость - измерение скорости всегда включается перед тем, как автомобиль тронется, то есть, начальная скорость будет равно 0, то тогда у нас же есть возможность рассчитать скорость в любой момент?

Comment: В теории - да.В сферическом вакууме - да. На практике - сильно много рассчетов, которые сильно будут понижать точность. Тот же телефон в процессе езды может сдвигаться, вибрировать и тому подобное. А это все вносить погрешность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно лучший вариант, это иметь собственный электронный датчик, который считает импульсы при обороте, обрабатывается формулой и результат выводится на device к примеру с помощью BLE. По сути это и есть реализация спидометра (электронного спидометра). Но так как вопрос в Android и необходимо мерить расстояние(что очень важно), ответ однозначно GPS.

Существуют реальные спидометры на основе только GPS. Они используют различные программы(алгоритмы) для обработки полученных данных, но суть всегда одна это формула расстояния: `S = v×t` Те: скорость = пройденное расстояние, делённое на время пути. Исходя именно из этого GPS очень подходит, хотя сама технология значительно сложней и показатели были бы идеальны, если б не было уйма погрешностей, [GPS - точность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS)

Акселерометр не подойдет для авто. Хотя частично, можно получить показания ну это очень тяжело. Простой пример: авто едет в горку, как реагировать на показания? А если при это ещё и поворачивает? Но если вы хотите разобраться, вот видео [Sensor Fusion on Android Devices:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) на 23:30, то что вам нужно и пример который я вам привел с машиной открывается где-то на 24:50.

Альтернатива: ГЛОНАСС (ГЛОНАСС+GPS).

Comment: Спасибо, очень развёрнутый ответ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Только GPS вам поможет в реально мире.

Ускорение будет очень шумные значения показывать. А по нашим дорогам - все равно, что в стиральную машину акселерометр забросить с кирпичами и поставить на отжим.